# Is there a method I can override on a JavaScript object to control what is displayed by console.log?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firebug

I'm thinking in particular of Chrome, though Firebug would be interesting to.  I've tried toString() and valueOf(), but neither of those seem to be used.  Interestingly, if I take a function it'll display the function definition - but then if I add a toString() method it will show null!

```
var a = function(){};
console.log(a); // output: function (){}
a.toString = function(){ return 'a'; };
console.log(a); // output: null
a.valueOf = function(){ return 'v'; };
console.log(a); // output: null
```

Any ideas?

Comment: see also [adjust console.log behaviour of custom object](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28397861/1048572) for a node.js environment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no way I know of. Your best bet will be to define a `toString()` method on the object you want to log and then call it, either directly or indirectly:

```
var o = {};
o.toString = function() {
    return "Three blind mice";
};

console.log("" + o);
console.log(o.toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for future readers, there is now a way to do exactly what is asked here.

For the solution please read this duplicated post:

[adjust console.log behaviour of custom object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28397861/adjust-console-log-behaviour-of-custom-object)

Comment: Also for future readers: the solution posted there works in Node, but not in browsers

Comment: @LGenzelis you are totally right, for some reason I was assuming NodeJS, sorry!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in Chrome nowadays with a devtools custom formatter. They don't seem to be officially documented anywhere, and aren't enabled by default -- so you have to enable them in (Dev Tools Settings) > Console > Enable Custom Formatters. But then you can add a custom formatter for your object:

```js
class CustomClass {
    constructor (foo, bar) { this.foo = foo; this.bar = bar; }
}

window.devtoolsFormatters = (window.devtoolsFormatters || []).concat([{
    header: (obj) => {
        if (obj instanceof CustomClass) {
            return ['div', {}, `CustomClass(${obj.foo}, ${obj.bar})`];
        } else {
            return null; // fall back to default formatter
        }
    },
    hasBody: () => true, // if the user can expand to get more info
    body: (obj) => {
        return ['div', {},
            ['span', {style: 'display: block; font-weight: bold'}, 'CustomClass'],
            ['span', {style: 'display: block; margin-left: 2em'}, `foo: ${obj.foo}`],
            ['span', {style: 'display: block; margin-left: 2em'}, `bar: ${obj.bar}`],
        ];
    }
}]);
```

A few words of warning:

- You must return a JsonML ([tag-name, attrs, children...]) list from the formatter. If you return an invalid JsonML or a bare string, it will either fail silently or throw an error.
- The formatter must have a header() and hasBody() function, and if hasBody() returns true, must have a body() function as well. Otherwise your formatter will be either silently ignored or throw an error.
- A lot of element types aren't supported. I was only able to get `div` and `span` to work; `p`, `strong`, and other elements all failed. But you can emulate them with CSS.
- The `window.devtoolsFormatters` array is null by default, but I added the check because extensions may already add their own custom formatters.

You can find a bit more information here: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1FTascZXT9cxfetuPRT2eXPQKXui4nWFivUnS_335T3U/preview

Answer (score 0):

You should get a better result from Firebug, you should get

```
var a = function(){};
console.log(a); // output: function 
a.toString = function(){ return 'a'; };
console.log(a); // output: function, {toString()}
a.valueOf = function(){ return 'v'; };
console.log(a); // output: function, {toString(), valueOf()}
```

http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=3117

Comment: I have to admit, I had actually not tried it in Firebug (I was a die-hard Firebug user, but I'm on on a Mac and Chrome feels just slightly less out of place than Firefox, so what with the built-in console being available in Chrome I've been kind of just using that recently).  I get "function()" as output on Firebug, which is at least less *puzzling* than the Chrome behavior of "setting toString() changes display, but not to the output of toString(), HAHAHA!"  And besides, it's not exactly a common use-case.  A Function with attributes added?  I'm a weirdo.

Comment: me too ;-)



and here some more characters then.