# adjust console.log behaviour of custom object

Tags: javascript, node.js

is there any way to influence what console.log gives out custom objects?
I tried to overwrite the customObject.prototype.toString method, that did not work though.

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't believe so, for debugging you could always add; `console.logg = function(o) { console.log(o.toString()); }`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a method I can override on a JavaScript object to control what is displayed by console.log?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2960936/is-there-a-method-i-can-override-on-a-javascript-object-to-control-what-is-displ)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In node.js, [`console.log`](http://nodejs.org/api/console.html#console_console_log_data) calls [`util.inspect`](http://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_object_options) on each argument without a formatting placeholder.  So if you define an `inspect(depth, opts)` method on your object it will be called to get your custom string representation of the object.

For example:

```
function Custom(foo) {
    this.foo = foo;
}

Custom.prototype.inspect = function(depth, opts) {
    return 'foo = ' + this.foo.toUpperCase();
};

var custom = new Custom('bar');
console.log(custom);
```

Outputs:

> foo = BAR

Or using a class:

```
class Custom {
    constructor(foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }

    inspect(depth, opts) {
        return 'foo = ' + this.foo.toUpperCase();
    }
}

var custom = new Custom('bar');
console.log(custom);
```

Comment: does defining a new inspect method has any other important implications?

Comment: @Moezalez Not that I know of, no.  According to the docs, the primary utility of `util.inspect` is for use in debugging, so this use of it is as intended.

Comment: Is there any equivalent option in browsers?

Comment: This no longer works as of Node v16+, at least. See the other answer.

Answer (score 32):

The previous answer has been deprecated in newer versions of node. The method one needs to implement now is the symbol `[util.inspect.custom]`.

For example:

```js
const util = require('util');

class Custom {
  constructor(foo, bar) {
    this.foo = foo;
    this.bar = bar;
  }

  [util.inspect.custom](depth, opts) {
    return this.foo + this.bar;
  }
}

console.log(new Custom(3, 5)); // Prints '8'
```

Comment: Could you please explain this syntax to me. I am new to JS

Comment: How can you do this in browsers?

Comment: @JacobWeisenburger You could implement something similar in browsers by creating your own `toString` method for the class and then calling that whenever you `console.log` the class, its less important to override the default behaviour for logging in browsers because presumably you'll only use it for debugging there.

Comment: @tbhaxor apologies for the late response but I'll reply anyway in case it end up being useful for somebody else. The `[util.inspect.custom]` method name is an example of [computed property names](https://eloquentcode.com/computed-property-names-in-javascript) where in this case the property name is a [symbol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol) referenced by `util.inspect.custom` the main reason for this is to guarantee its uniqueness.

Answer (score 5):

Recent (18) Node.js version has this documentation snippet as an example of how to do this across Node and Browsers:

```js
const customInspectSymbol = Symbol.for('nodejs.util.inspect.custom');

class Password {
  constructor(value) {
    this.value = value;
  }

  toString() {
    return 'xxxxxxxx';
  }

  [customInspectSymbol](depth, inspectOptions, inspect) {
    return `Password <${this.toString()}>`;
  }
}

const password = new Password('r0sebud');
console.log(password);
// Prints Password <xxxxxxxx>
```