# Javascript: How can I return console.log result into string form?

Tags: javascript

As title, I am getting the result that I wanted from console.log(result), however, how can I pass this console.log result to the string variable and "return" it? I am having trouble returning the result of console.log(). Thanks!

```
var type = ["men","women","boys", "girls"]
var product = "women shoes";
product.split(' ').forEach(function(item){
    type.forEach(function(elem){
      if(elem==item){
        console.log(elem);
      }
    });
});
```

Thank you for all the answers here, and it is so amazing that so many people are willing to help my beginner problem. Let me clear my question a little bit here, like above, console.log (elem) will return woman, however, if i replace the line concole.log(elem) with return(elem) will get me nothing. Why is that?

Comment: why don't you just return the `result` variable in your `console.log()` ?

Comment: I don't understand. `console.log` will just print whatever value you pass it to the console. That same value is still available. Could you please create a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us your problem?

Comment: Do you want to convert result to a string? Then JSON.stringify is your friend: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Comment: As @PatrickHund said, if you are logging and array and you want to get the string of the array you should consider using `JSON.stringify()` but once again, this question lack a lot of information.

Answer (score 3):

`console.log` formats whatever you pass inside to a string and outputs it. You can do the same, by explicitly calling `toString()` as follows:

```
console.log(result);

return result.toString();
```

As mentioned in the comments by @Patrick Hund, if result is a Javascript object, you can use `JSON.stringify` to convert it to a string (and then return it) as follows:

```
return JSON.stringify(result, null, 2);
```

Comment: This is not completely correct. As described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28397861/adjust-console-log-behaviour-of-custom-object the behaviour for Node.js may be different