# Get specific property instead of Object if I call Just Object

Tags: javascript, object, properties

I want to create object with many variables.
But if I call this object without any child method/property, it must return property instead object.

Example:

```js
let entries = {
  alex: {
    _this_: "Alex Example", // "_this_", "_self" or something like that. You catch, what I want to say. ;)
    age: 21,
    gender: "female"
  }
}

console.log(entries.alex);
// Normal:> Object{...}
// I want:> "Alex Example"

console.log(entries.alex.age);
// Normal/I want:> 21
```

I searched almost 3 month, but still no hope.

Sorry for my English BTW. Not native Speaker.
Also that's my very first question. so THX.

Comment: Just like Discord.js module do. `msg` itself is object but while calling `console.log(msg)` return `msg.content` property instead

Comment: Does this answer your question? [adjust console.log behaviour of custom object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28397861/adjust-console-log-behaviour-of-custom-object)

Comment: similar but not solve. I'm going to close question in that case.